# Run task in background iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have a FireMonkey application who needs to check for events at a certain interval.

Is there a way I can execute a function at a certain time even if the application is closed?

Comment: Natively, you can do this. See [Background Execution and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20).

Comment: Why a down vote on this question ??? I upvoted it to compensate.

Comment: @RegisSt-Gelais : This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center :))

Comment: I voted to close it as off-topic because it shows no effort to do any research. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)." This question shows no effort to research the subject, no efforts to check the Apple documentation to investigate a solution, nothing but typing two sentences here. (The answer to the question asked is "Yes".)

Comment: @KenWhite my firend how can I do some research if I can't find any single reference to this problem and I never developed software for iOS in my entire life? I was asking for a starting point I really write code that I do understand ;)

Comment: You clearly can't do something when your application is closed. So you need to be able to perform a scheduled task. You could start with that, I think. "Scheduled task iOS" might be a good search expression. In Windows, that might be a service app. So "scheduled service iOS" might be an alternative. (Not having developed iOS software isn't a valid reason; I'd never done an Android app or used Java, but I've now done both (and done an Android app in Delphi XE5), and I'd never done a Windows app when Windows was released.)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for your googling tips but unfortunately that's not enough

Answer (score -1):

In iOS 7 Apple has introduced Background Transfer. You can handle entire background activities with the help of this.

This is the code you have to write in AppDelegate.m in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

[application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

You can also set your custom time interval instead of predefined time interval.